# How can I change (with Kotlin) which item my spinner selects?

Tags: java, android, kotlin

[function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1TR7.png)

```
    private fun updateCurrencySpinner() {
// Update selected item form the currency spinner based on the country spinner
val currency = when (serviceSpinner.selectedItemPosition) {
    0 -> 0
    1 -> 0
    2 -> 1
    3 -> 2
    else -> 0
}
currenciesSpinner.setSelection(currency)
}
```

[when i call the function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8sQS5.png)

```
        countrySpinner.onItemSelectedListener = object : AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    override fun onItemSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?, view: View?, position: Int, id: Long) {
        updateCurrencySpinner()
    }

    override fun onNothingSelected(parent: AdapterView<*>?) {}
}
```

can someone tell me why my spinner does not update (I call this function every time I change the selected item)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You call `updateCurrencySpinner` when `countrySpinner` changes, but you don't use the value of `countrySpinner`, instead you use the value of `serviceSpinner`.

So even if you call the method when `countrySpinner` changes, it does not actually change anything because the value of `serviceSpinner` is still the same.

Comment: You're asome. I love you. How can I thank you?